# sql add row extract

Tags: sql, select

This is my datatable:

[image]

I want to get result like this:

[image]

my sql is

```
select EXTRACT(MONTH from create_time) as time, count(keyword)  as keyword
from b_project 
where keyword like '%区块链%' 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH from create_time)
```

With above code i get this result:

[image]

I want to add row with name 区块链. ,i know there is some wrong with my code .How to modify it?

Comment: You are not including the actual keyword in your SELECT list. Try "SELECT keyword, EXTRACT(....), count(...) as count...."

Comment: "select  keyword, EXTRACT(MONTH from create_time) as time, count(keyword)  as keyword
from b_project 
where keyword like '%区块链%' 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH from create_time) "      it does not work with this.

Comment: you need a few other modifications try the answer I gave below. I edited it so that you are added the keyword to group by and changed the count to count(*). let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: For month 9 there are three records with different keywords. Which of these do you want to display? Then add that to your select list, e.g. `SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM create_time) AS create_month, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
MIN(Keyword) AS keyword`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a constant 区块链 and not each keyword, I think this will do that:

```
select '区块链' as x, EXTRACT(MONTH from create_time) as time, count(keyword)  as keyword
from b_project 
where keyword like '%区块链%' 
GROUP BY '区块链', EXTRACT(MONTH from create_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to select the `keyword` and add the word 'month' to your month field after you cast it to nvarchar.

```
select keyword,  EXTRACT(MONTH from create_time)   as time, count(*)  as keyword
from b_project 
where keyword like '%区块链%' 
GROUP BY keyword, EXTRACT(MONTH from create_time)
```

Comment: the error like this "from b_project 
where keyword like '%区块链%' 
GROUP BY keyword, EXTRACT(MONTH from create_time)
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'nvarchar(2)) + ' month')   as time, count(*)  as keyword
  from b_project 
  where' at line 1"

Comment: OK, I thought you were using T-sql. I will take out the cast.  you'll have to figure out how to add the word month to your month number